# How to generate all possible list from given range of list which will target given input sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Input: Target sum

Output: count of all possible permutations with given sum from list [1,2,3]

Example input: 4 and corresponding output: 7

All possible pairs:

```
1, 1, 1, 1
1, 2, 1
1, 1, 2   
1, 3    
2, 1, 1    
2, 2    
3, 1
```

For these given permutations for explanation of output these all must be taken from `[1,2,3]` for any input.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):

    rests = [[] for _ in range(target)]
    for num in candidates:
        if num > target:
            continue
        else:
            rests[target - num].append([num])
        for cur_rest in range(target - 1, num - 1, -1):
            for result in rests[cur_rest]:
                rests[cur_rest - num].append(result + [num])

    return rests[0]

s=Solution()
c=[1,2,3]
t=int(input())
print(s.combinationSum(c,t))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and what is a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will even have rewards at visiting those pages. We will not write code for you/do your home work. Share what you have tried so far and we will try to improve it.

Comment: i was trying this in python

Comment: You can edit your post to add this code, much more readable

Comment: def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):
        rests = [[] for _ in range(target)]
        for num in candidates:
            if num > target:
                continue
            else:
                rests[target - num].append([num])
            for cur_rest in range(target - 1, num - 1, -1):
                for result in rests[cur_rest]:
                    rests[cur_rest - num].append(result + [num])
        
        return rests[0]

s=Solution()
c=[1,2,3]
t=int(input())
print(s.combinationSum(c,t))

Comment: Please put this code inside your question by pressing the `edit` button under the tags. Comments lose the format

Comment: I have one doubt after reading your NOTE. Is list will always be same as [1,2,3] for any input number, lets say 230 ?

Comment: Also, `1, 1, 1, 1` is not a pair...

Comment: This is problem of Permutations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all combinations of a list of numbers with a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517540/find-all-combinations-of-a-list-of-numbers-with-a-given-sum)

Comment: actually in given input sum=4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517540/find-all-combinations-of-a-list-of-numbers-with-a-given-sum

Comment: its not solution

Comment: It is with minor modifications...

Comment: hmmm..will try to solve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all combinations of list elements including duplicate elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239927/find-all-combinations-of-list-elements-including-duplicate-elements)

Answer (score 0):

As per solution suggested by @Tomerikoo, I have created solution with some modification.

```
    def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):
        # List for storing possible all sequence of permutations
        seq_list = []

        # This loop will generate all possible permutation for given candidates
        for i in range(1, target + 1):
           # Extend given list with cartesian product of given candidates

           # To calculate cartesian product set use itertools.product with candidates
           # with set size ranging from 1 to target number
           # This is necessary as we have to find all possible combinations
           seq_list.extend([p for p in itertools.product(candidates, repeat=i)])

        # Just select those sequence whose sum is target
        result = [seq for seq in seq_list if sum(seq) == target]

        # Return length of result set
        return len(result)

s=Solution() 
c=[1,2,3] 
t=int(input()) 
print(s.combinationSum(c,t))
```

Hope this help!!!