# Pandas find all combinations of rows under a budget

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

I am trying to figure out a way to determine all possible combinations of rows within a DataFrame that are below a budget, so let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = [['Bread', 9, 'Food'], ['Shoes', 20, 'Clothes'], ['Shirt', 15, 'Clothes'], ['Milk', 5, 'Drink'], ['Cereal', 8, 'Food'], ['Chips', 10, 'Food'], ['Beer', 15, 'Drink'], ['Popcorn', 3, 'Food'], ['Ice Cream', 6, 'Food'], ['Soda', 4, 'Drink']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Item', 'Price', 'Type'])
df
```

Data

```
Item       Price  Type
Bread      9      Food
Shoes      20     Clothes
Shirt      15     Clothes
Milk       5      Drink
Cereal     8      Food
Chips      10     Food
Beer       15     Drink
Popcorn    3      Food
Ice Cream  6      Food
Soda       4      Drink
```

I want to find every combination that I could purchase for under a specific budget, let's say $35 for this example, while only getting one of each type. I'd like to get a new dataframe made up of rows for each combination that works with each item in its own column.

I was trying to do it using itertools.product, but this can combine and add columns, but what I really need to do is combine and add a specific column based on values in another column. I'm a bit stumped now.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what's the expected result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517540/find-all-combinations-of-a-list-of-numbers-with-a-given-sum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here a way using `powerset` recipe from `itertools` with `pd.concat`

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

df_groups = pd.concat([df.reindex(l).assign(grp=n) for n, l in 
                       enumerate(powerset(df.index)) 
                       if (df.loc[l, 'Price'].sum() <= 35)])
```

Outputs a single dataframe with groups of product that meet $35 condition:

```
          Item  Price     Type  grp
0       Bread      9     Food    1
1       Shoes     20  Clothes    2
2       Shirt     15  Clothes    3
3        Milk      5    Drink    4
4      Cereal      8     Food    5
..        ...    ...      ...  ...
3        Milk      5    Drink  752
4      Cereal      8     Food  752
7     Popcorn      3     Food  752
8   Ice Cream      6     Food  752
9        Soda      4    Drink  752
```

How many ways this came combined to meet $35 budget?

```
df_groups['grp'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
258
```

*Details:*

There are a couple of tricks/methods that are used here.  First, we are using the index of the dataframe to create groups of rows or items using `powerset`.  Next, we are using `enumerate` to identify each group and with `assign` creating a new column in a dataframe with that group number from enumerate.

#### Modify to capture no more than one of each type:

```
df_groups = pd.concat([df.reindex(l).assign(grp=n) for n, l in 
                       enumerate(powerset(df.index)) 
                       if ((df.loc[l, 'Price'].sum() <= 35) & 
                           (df.loc[l, 'Type'].value_counts()==1).all())])
```

How many groups?

```
df_groups['grp'].nunique()
62
```

#### Get exactly one for each Type:

```
df_groups = pd.concat([df.reindex(l).assign(grp=n) for n, l in 
                       enumerate(powerset(df.index)) 
                       if ((df.loc[l, 'Price'].sum() <= 35) & 
                           (df.loc[l, 'Type'].value_counts()==1).all()&
                           (len(df.loc[l, 'Type']) == 3))])
```

How many groups?

```
df_groups['grp'].nunique()
21
```

Comment: Great! How could I limit it and require it to have only 1 item from each type?

Comment: @Emac You need to modify the if part of the list comprehension. See update.

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! Thank you sir, you figured it all out very quick!  Great job.

Comment: @Emac Thank you.  Happy coding.