# Finding combinations that meet thresholds for subgroups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-itertools, knapsack-problem

I need to find all the combinations of rows where multiple conditions are met. 
I tried to use the powerset recipe from itertools and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58119966/12225469) by adding multiple conditions but can't seem to get the conditions to work properly.
The code I've come up with is:

```
def powerset(iterable):
"powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
s = list(iterable)
return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

df_groups = pd.concat(
                  [data.reindex(l).assign(Group = n) for n, l in 
                   enumerate(powerset(data.index)) ])
                   if ((data.loc[l, 'Account'] == 'COS').any() & (data.loc[l,'Amount'].sum() >= 100)
                        & (data.loc[l,'Account'] == 'Rev').any() & (data.loc[l, 'Amount'].sum() >= 150)
                        & (data.loc[l,'Account'] == 'Inv').any() and (data.loc[l, 'Amount'].sum() >= 60)))] )
```

What I'm trying to do above is find only those combinations where the the following thresholds are met/exceeded:

```
Account     Amount
COS         150 
Rev         100 
Inv         60
```

---

Sample data:

```
Entity  Account Amount  Location
A10      Rev    60       A
B01      Rev    90       B
C11      Rev    80       C
B01      COS    90       B
C11      COS    80       C
A10      Inv    60       A
```

Apologies in advance for the poor question writing etiquette, its the first time I haven't been able to find an answer on Stackoverflow and have had to ask a question. 
Also, aware that this will get very slow as len(data) increases so any suggestions on that end are also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by creating the dataframe that OP mentions in the question

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Entity': ['A10', 'B01', 'C11', 'B01', 'C11', 'A10'],
                     'Account': ['Rev', 'Rev', 'Rev', 'COS', 'COS', 'Inv'],
                        'Amount': [60, 90, 80, 90, 80, 60],
                        'Location': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A']})

[Out]:
  Entity Account  Amount Location
0    A10     Rev      60        A
1    B01     Rev      90        B
2    C11     Rev      80        C
3    B01     COS      90        B
4    C11     COS      80        C
5    A10     Inv      60        A
```

Then, in order to achieve OP's goal of filtering based on specific constraints, one can do this using a one-liner with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), as follows

```
df_new = pd.concat([df[df['Account'] == 'Rev'].query('Amount <= 100'), df[df['Account'] == 'COS'].query('Amount <= 150'),  df[df['Account'] == 'Inv'].query('Amount <= 60')])

[Out]:
  Entity Account  Amount Location
0    A10     Rev      60        A
1    B01     Rev      90        B
2    C11     Rev      80        C
3    B01     COS      90        B
4    C11     COS      80        C
5    A10     Inv      60        A
```

As the sample dataframe doesn't allow us to get a clear picture if it is working or not, let us create a new random dataframe for testing purposes.

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Entity': np.random.choice(['A10', 'B01', 'C11', 'B01', 'C11', 'A10'], 1000),
                        'Account': np.random.choice(['Rev', 'COS', 'Inv'], 1000),
                        'Amount': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000),
                        'Location': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], 1000)})

[Out]:
  Entity Account  Amount Location
0    B01     Rev     497        A
1    B01     Rev      52        C
2    B01     Rev      42        C
3    B01     Rev     285        B
4    A10     COS     714        B
5    A10     Rev     288        B
6    B01     Rev     396        B
7    A10     Inv     277        B
8    C11     Inv     435        C
9    C11     COS     228        C
```

If one runs the one-liner on that newly created dataframe, one gets the following

```
df_new = pd.concat([df[df['Account'] == 'Rev'].query('Amount <= 100'), df[df['Account'] == 'COS'].query('Amount <= 150'),  df[df['Account'] == 'Inv'].query('Amount <= 60')])


[Out]:
    Entity Account  Amount Location
1      B01     Rev      52        C
2      B01     Rev      42        C
21     B01     Rev       1        A
31     C11     Rev      38        A
47     A10     Rev      83        C
60     B01     Rev      41        C
156    B01     Rev      81        C
197    C11     Rev      61        C
206    C11     Rev      90        A
224    C11     Rev      23        B
```

which, from the sample we are seeing, it does satisfy the requirements.

---

There are additional ways to solve this.

Another example is using [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and a lambda function as follows

```
df_new = df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Amount'] <= 100 if x['Account'] == 'Rev' else x['Amount'] <= 150 if x['Account'] == 'COS' else x['Amount'] <= 60, axis=1)]
```