# Pandas get row combination and group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

[image]

I have to find all the combinations of Group (let's say 2 pairs) and then have to group them across unique ID's

Output:

[image]

Currently I found a way to generate all the combinations but cannot seem to group by unique ID's

I referred to below links as well:
[Pandas find all combinations of rows under a budget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119575/pandas-find-all-combinations-of-rows-under-a-budget)

Code to generate the pairs:

```
from itertools import combinations
li_4 =[]
for index in list(combinations(df.group.unique(),2)):
       li_4.append([index[0],index[1]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `merge` then `np.sort` and pass the result to `crosstab` after remove the duplicate with `drop_duplicates`

```
s = df.merge(df,on='Id')
s['New'] = list(map(lambda x : ''.join(x),np.sort(s[['Group_x','Group_y']].values,axis=1).tolist()))
s = s.drop_duplicates(['Id','New'])
s = pd.crosstab(s.Id,s.New)
s
Out[88]: 
New  aa  ab  ac  ad  af  bb  bc  bd  be  bf  cc  cd  dd  de  ee  ff
Id                                                                 
2     1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
3     0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0
4     1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
```