# How do I fill out a list of N length based on budget and price values from a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iterator

I have the following df of fruits:

```
    fruit            cost
0   Banana             10 
1   Apple               5        
2   Orange              4
3   Grape               2
4   Kiwi                3
```

I want to create a list of 3 fruits (obligatory - no more, no less) with a budget of $15. The df is already ordered so I want to start choosing fruits from the first row and iterate through the df.

The list wound end up being (accounting for budget and fruit limit):

```
[Banana, Grape, Kiwi]
```

This is my code:

```
def fruit_list(df, budget = 15)
    list = []
    budget = budget
    iter = df.iterrows()
    for (i, row1), (j, row2) in zip(iter, iter):
        if (len(list) < 3 and budget > row1['cost'] and 
            budget - row1['cost'] > row2['cost']):
            list.append(row1['fruit'])
            budget -= row1['cost']
    return fruit_list
```

My code is leaving a 2-fruit list, instead of 3. Basically I would like my code to compare a fruit's price with ALL of the remaining fruit's prices and not just the next one. How should I tackle this?

*****(EXTRA)*** This is what the iterating process should look like:

Budget = $15

Iteration 1 --> Banana

- Add Banana to list
- Budget = $15 - $10 = $5*

Iteration 2 --> Apple

- SKIP Apple because:
- Budget = $5 - $5 = $0
- No more budget to buy more fruits, and I need 3 fruits

Iteration 3 --> Orange

- SKIP Orange because:
- Budget = $5 - $4 = $1
- Not enough budget to buy any of the remaining fruits, and I need 3 fruits

Iteration 4 --> Grape

- Add Grape to list
- Budget = $5 - $2 = $3
- Enough budget to buy the remaining fruit, Kiwi

Iteration 5 --> Kiwi

- Add Kiwi to list
- Budget = $3 - $3 = $0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58119966/6361531

Comment: Do you want an exact budget match? If not do you need to maximize/minimize the budget? In my answer below I assumed an exact match (or the first match even if not not optimal if you were to use `<=15` in place of `=15`)

Answer (score 0):

As you have a fixed number of items and want the first match, this is easily done in pure python by looping through the `combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

s = df.set_index('fruit')['cost']

out = next((c for c in combinations(df['fruit'], 3)
            if s.loc[list(c)].sum()==15), None)
```

Output: `('Banana', 'Grape', 'Kiwi')`

Since we are using a generator here, the computation stops as soon as we found a match without needlessly computing the rest of the combinations.