# Find a combination of L numbers from 1 to N so that their sum is equal to N

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, subset-sum

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

L = 3 N = 100
combination = np.tile(np.arange(1, N+1), [L, 1])

combine = product(*combination, repeat=1)
```

number of placements with repetitions : 100^3
but we only need those that are equal to N

```
r = 0
for comb in combine:
    if sum(comb)==L:
        r += 1
```

r will be equal = 4851
but the number of operations will be = 1000000

#### How to optimize your code to avoid so many unnecessary repetitions?

Comment: If `L` is small compared to `N`, you can just set `r = list(range(1,L))` and then return `r + [N - sum(r)]]`. For instance for `L=4, N=100`, return `[1, 2, 3, 94]`.

Comment: Note that your question is inconsistent with your code. Your question specifically asks about *finding one combination* of numbers that have the correct sum. But your python code is *counting* a number of combinations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all combinations of a list of numbers with a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517540/find-all-combinations-of-a-list-of-numbers-with-a-given-sum)

Comment: Better duplicate with more detailed answer: [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)