# OR-Tools solution to partition the data so that subset of rows where every feature falls in the corresponding range maximizes the objective function

Tags: python, r, optimization, or-tools

Cross-posted from https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/153558/find-a-range-of-values-to-subset-the-rows-to-maximize-the-objective-function?noredirect=1#comment323025_153558.

I have searched around for some time but couldn't find a similar example to my problem.
It looks common enough that I would expect it to be solved. It lies between search and optimization/regression.
The goal is to find a range of values for each feature, so that the subset of rows where every feature falls in the corresponding range maximizes the objective function.
Assume we have a matrix with Yi and corresponding set of features Xi (say around 40).
Number of samples relatively large, 100k+.
[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKSQ2.png)

So in this case for the total data Sum(Y_i) = 73 and the mean(Y_i)= 6.0833

The problem is to:

Max sum(Yi) subj  to:

mean(Y_i) > 7$

sum(i) > 5000

, where i are the row index and rows are selected by imposing 2 constraints ( < and > ) or each feature.

I have managed to get solution using DEoptim in R for 5-6 variables with 2 conditions (partitions) "<" and ">". For more features it gets slow/fail to converge.

Seeing the (somewhat) similar question (and answer) here : [Pandas find subset of rows minimizing the sum of a column under other column constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69473985/pandas-find-subset-of-rows-minimizing-the-sum-of-a-column-under-other-column-con)

I am wondering if there is a way to formulate my problem in OR-Tools as well. I have went through the documentation on the https://developers.google.com/optimization but still struggle to understand how to express my problem.

Would appreciate any pointers as to how to formulate (solve) this problem in OR-tools in the general case, where there is a dataset with features + response variable and the objective is find the splits on features to maximize (minimize) the sum (or other function) of the response variable.
The number of splits should be 2 per feature as we want solution to be locally monotonic wrt to features.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63377180/finding-ideal-filter-setting-to-maximize-target-function/63429510#63429510

Comment: Most likely, the technique to use will be a MIP solver. There should be plenty of literature on this if it can be applied.

Comment: this seems deterministic: order by `Y` take all values larger than 7 and keep adding until mean falls below 7. If length of selected values is higher than 5000 you have global maximum otherwise there is no feasible solution.